# .Net Core MVC notyf (notification) pop-up

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to show notyf message just using c#. I cant see notification message because of return view(). How can I show?
My codes like that.

```
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                notyf.Warning("Entity null");
                return View();
            }

            categoryService.Insert(entity);
            notyf.Success("WellDone.");

            return RedirectToAction("ListCategory");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            notyf.Error("serviceError" + ex.Message, 12);
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the readme in this link. I follow the steps and it works for me.

[ToastNotification - Elegant Notifications For ASP.NET Core Applications](https://github.com/aspnetcorehero/ToastNotification)

**My test sample code:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]